# Replace columns with the same value between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1

```
    Date    RPM
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   0
6   6   0
7   7   0
```

and df2

```
    Date    RPM
0   0   0
1   2   2
2   4   4
3   6   6
```

I want to replace the RPM in df1 with the RPM in df2 where they have the same Date

I tried with replace but it didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created from `df2` and then replace misisng valeus by original column by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['RPM'] = df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['RPM']).fillna(df1['RPM'])
```

Comment: Could I ask you to explain what is going on in that fairly-long one-liner, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the two frames on the Date column to get the new RPM against the corresponding date row:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left', suffixes=[None, ' new'])

   Date  RPM  RPM new
0     1    0      NaN
1     2    0      2.0
2     3    0      NaN
3     4    0      4.0
4     5    0      NaN
5     6    0      6.0
6     7    0      NaN
```

You can then fill in the nans in RPM new using [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to get the RPM column:

```
df['RPM'] = df['RPM new'].fillna(df['RPM'])

   Date  RPM  RPM new
0     1  0.0      NaN
1     2  2.0      2.0
2     3  0.0      NaN
3     4  4.0      4.0
4     5  0.0      NaN
5     6  6.0      6.0
6     7  0.0      NaN
```

Then [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `RPM new` column:

```
df = df.drop('RPM new', axis=1)

   Date  RPM
0     1  0.0
1     2  2.0
2     3  0.0
3     4  4.0
4     5  0.0
5     6  6.0
6     7  0.0
```

Full code:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left', suffixes=[None, ' new'])
df['RPM'] = df['RPM new'].fillna(df['RPM'])
df = df.drop('RPM new', axis=1)
```